# ETL - Push data from oracle db to aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl

I have an oracle db which has about 20 tables. I would like to push the data from the oracle tables into a S3 bucket. I would like to do this realtime or at worst near-realtime. Once the data is fetched I may have to do some small amount of data transformation - eg: obfuscate sensitive data or make an external service call to tokenize sensitive data. I saw that amazon aws glue is an etl tool but I wasn't sure if it is fit for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Data Firehose is ideal for that case. If you want to do the transformation, you can introduce Lambda. Every record will get delivered to lambda before delivering to the destination and you can introduce masking or transforming any of your data to the destination.

**Data-Transformation:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html

**Oracle to AWS Kinesis Data Firehose:**
Xplenty takes your oracle data and deliver it to firehose.

https://www.xplenty.com/integrations/oracle/amazon-kinesis-firehose/

Hope it helps.

**Without Xplenty:**

You can follow the documentation to create trigger under ORACLE to trigger lambda to deliver the record.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/from-sql-to-microservices-integrating-aws-lambda-with-relational-databases/

> ORACLE -- Lambda (Handles Triggers and Transformation) -- Firehose --
>   S3

Comment: Thanks @Kannaiyan. Will EMR be suitable for this use case or is it for a different purpose?

Comment: Does firehose detect change to tables and fetch data from oracle tables?

Comment: Xplenty does that, It runs the query and pumps the data to firehose. If you want to transform the data, you can write a simple code for masking or changing it in the lambda. It is just for data transformation. Rest of the process of compressing and deliverying it to S3 it taken care by firehose.

Comment: While you can use EMR for it, I'm not finding the need for it. Firehose, Lambda and S3 are scalable computes and storages. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Kannaiyan. Is xplenty an external service that I need to add. If i cannot find it within my enterprise's marketplace are there any alternatives available for polling oracle db for changes?

Comment: Updated without Xplenty

Comment: My use case is similar just that I want the data on a daily basis from Oracle DB to AWS S3. Which connector should I use (NiFi and SnapLogic comes with a cost), I want to use something which can be used through AWS itself (maybe another service of AWS). How should I go about it? What are the options and what is the best among them and why?